# Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty) doesn't install properly

Tags: 11.04, installation, troubleshooting

I have a new computer and want to install ubuntu on it. I downloaded the .iso and burnt it to a disk, but whenever I select install, it comes up with an error. I have tried with numerous disks, but with no change. It is also super slow to get to that stage. Could you please help?

- The error says: A serious error has occurred. Ubuntu will switch to desktop view so you can see the error and retry installation.
- I have checked the CD for errors and it passes all the tests

Comment: Could you tell us what error it gave ?

Comment: The error says: A serious error has occurred. Ubuntu will switch to desktop view so you can see the error and retry installation.

Comment: Can you check the CD for errors? Press any key when you see a purple screen to get to the options menu in the Live CD.

Comment: I checked the disk and it said there was no problems.

Comment: In general when Ubuntu encounters an error it will give you some form of diagnostic code or clue as to what caused it and this will help in troubleshooting the issue. If you can provide this or some more detailed info we should be able to troubleshoot your problem better. When you say you checked the disc did you complete an MD5 checksum on it?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, then please flag explaining that (as well as editing your question with any details you have).

Answer (score 2):

First thing to check is that your ISO image is good. Run a md5 checksum on the file and make sure it validates against the one published on the ubuntu downloads page.

When you make a CD from the ISO always set the burner to run a check at the end. This ensures that the CD has been made correctly.

I've had issues with some brands/batches of CDs where they would be OK for audio recording but have errors for any digital stuff. Make sure your disks are reasonable quality, free of scratches and dust.

Last time I installed Ubuntu (just a week ago) I used my USB thumb for the image rather than a CD. It was so much faster running off of the USB. I'd recommend doing this method to anyone who has a suitable computer. Most modern systems can boot from USB thumbs and the Ubuntu download page has a link to the software you need to format a bootable USB thumb.